# Filter out ReSharper files in Github for Windows

Tags: github, resharper, gitignore

This has been asked probably several times, and I've tried a lot of proposed .gitignore entries, but I can't seem to be able to filter out the ._ReSharper .crc files from my GitHub for Windows commits.

I have several ReSharper-related entries in .gitingore:

`*\_ReSharper*` 
`_ReSharper*` 
`_ReSharper.*`

but no matter what, .crc files are to be commited:

[image]

What entry should I use to prevent RS stuff from commiting to my repo?

Answer (score 1):

This works for me: `_ReSharper*/`